# While dragging multiple items from listview deselecting list items

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to build a WPF application which contains a `ListView` that allows multiple selections and allows the user to drag and drop selected items into another `ListView`.  I've been able to get drag and drop to work fine, but I'm having some trouble working with the behaviour of `ListView` when dragging the mouse on them.

If the user clicks on an item and holds down the mouse button and then begins to drag, 
the `ListView` will change the selection(deselecting list items) as the user drags over other items.  I don't want it to do this- when the user clicks an item and holds the button down, I want the item that they clicked on to always be selected, regardless of where they move the mouse.

Here is my `ListView` properties I set, Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720459/drag-multiple-files-in-listview/53721045#53721045) for complete code

```
<ListView Width="auto" Height="280" KeyDown="RightFolderListing_KeyDown" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AllowDrop="True"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="RightList_LeftButtonDown" DragEnter="RightList_DragEnter" Drop="RightList_DropEnter" PreviewMouseMove="RightList_PreviewMouseMove" SelectionMode="Extended"
                        util:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" Name="RightFolderListing" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RightListViewItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding RightFolderList, ElementName=RPCFTViewer,Mode=TwoWay}" ContextMenuOpening="RightFolderListing_ContextMenuOpening"  >
```

Comment: You could add a column to the `ListView` containing a `CheckBox` to select items

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but see if adding `e.Handled = true;` to the LeftList_PreviewMouseMove() method helps.

Comment: Looking at that code, calling BeginDrag() on every mouse move event might cause a problem, as it could result in the object being dragged changing as the mouse moves across the ListView items. Perhaps try adding a bool (e.g. "_dragStarted"), set this to false in LeftList_LeftButtonDown(), wrap the call to BeginDrag() in a `if (!_dragStarted)` block, and also set the flag to true here.

Comment: @AndrewStephens thanks for ur reply,  BeginDrag() is not calling at every mouse move calling only when drag happens.